# "ResolvePackageAssets" and "GetPackageDirectories" tasks both failing since installing TelerikUI controls

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, telerik

I installed the TelerikUI controller for a project, which I ended up not using at all. I unistalled it but now I get two errors, both have the same number: (MSB4018) -The "GetPackageDirectory" task failed unexpectedly- and -The "ResolvePackageAssets" task failed unexpectedly-. Because of these errors I am unable to install and delete packages from NuGet, and its making previously compiled code from other projects not recognize NuGet packages. I´ve been searching for a solution online, most of them pointing to the nuget.config file, however when opening this file it seems like the file was not modified by the TelerikUI. My guess is that the TelerikUI changed my NuGet package directories, and now visual studio is looking for them in the wrong directories, which causes these errors, and if that´s the case I don´t know how to change it back to the original settings. I´m fairly new to visual studio and this is the first time i´ve encountered this error. I´m using the VS2019 community edition.

Comment: Hi, any update about this issue?

Comment: Thank you for your answer @PerryQian-MSFT. I switched to a new computer at work and ended formatting the old one, so I never really had to deal with the issue anymore, and never really solved it haha. Thanks for helping though!

Comment: Ohh! all right. And be glad to know that you will never face the issue~

Answer (score 2):

Try the following suggestions:

**1)** add these on the `xxx.csproj` file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <RestoreFallbackFolders>clear</RestoreFallbackFolders>
</PropertyGroup>
```

**2)** [clean nuget caches first](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) or just all files under `C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages`

also, delete `bin` and `obj` folder.

then, type `update-package -reinstall` under **Tools**-->**Nuget Package Manager**--> **Package Manager Console**.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue in my project by editing my `.csproj` file and adding `<DisableImplicitNuGetFallbackFolder>` element inside my `<PropertyGroup>` to `true`:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <DisableImplicitNuGetFallbackFolder>true</DisableImplicitNuGetFallbackFolder>
</PropertyGroup>
```

The solution was found via the following link:

https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/7414#issuecomment-472561481